# How to force MySQL to create FULLTEXT index of words with 1, 2, and 3 letters?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, full-text-search

How to force MySQL to create FULLTEXT index of words with 1, 2, and 3 letters?

Because in my table, many of the important contents have words of 3 letters like 'PHP','ASP', etc. And I just can't search for these rows using 'MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)'. I don't want to use 'LIKE' coz I want the better performance when performing search.

Any method to change this behaviour of MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the **ft_min_word_len** and ft_max_word_len system variables. (See Section 5.1.3, “Server System Variables”.) The default minimum value is four characters; the default maximum is version dependent. If you change either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

I hope you will be able to change this variable..!

Comment: yeah, got my mysql.ini changed now, tks :)